# What trigonometric identities was used to get this?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

I have this solution for a math question, but I didn't get how did we get from the line $3$ to $4$ and also from $4$ to $5$. I can understand that this is done through trigonometric identities. but which ones?

The question is

[image]

Comment: What is $j{}{}$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: this is complex number that's why j is used

Comment: $i=j=\sqrt{-1}$ both are used, latter more in electrical engg.

Comment: @markvs In complex numbers, usually $i$ is used to represent $\sqrt{-1}$; in electrical engineering, $i$ represents current, so $j$ is used instead.

Comment: @bjcolby: I think that number $i$ was introduced **long before** electric currents were discovered. So electrical engineers should choose another letter.

Comment: @markvs: Agreed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The identities are...

- $e^{jt} = \cos t + j \sin t$
- $\Re (e^{jt}) = \cos jt = \dfrac {e^{jt} + e^{-jt}}{2}$ and $\Im (e^{jt}) = \sin jt = \dfrac {e^{jt} - e^{-jt}}{2i}$
- $a \sin t + b \cos t = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \cos\left(t + \arctan \left(-\dfrac {b}{a}\right)\right)$

Note: I am using $j$ here as in the exercise, but usually the imaginary unit for $\sqrt {-1}$ is $i$.

Comment: @markvs Ha...I knew I was missing something in the formula!  Thanks for catching this - I've updated my post.

Comment: thanks a lot for all answers and especially @bjcolby15 you are a life saver, i have never seen the third identity before that's why i was so confused. but dont you think it should be arctan -b/a ?

Comment: @zed_eln No problem! You are right, however, that it should be $-\dfrac {b}{a}$.  I have corrected my post.

Answer (score 1):

The entire calculation seems highly suspect to me, not just due to the (not entirely consistent) use of trig identities, but also due to an earlier step.

I will use $i$ for the imaginary unit. I will also insert some parentheses since I really dislike reading notation like $i\pi/2t$.

In the absence of a definition of $X$ I will have to assume that the derivation of this equation from the summation form is correct:
$$ 
x(t) = 6 + (-4 - 2i) e^{i(\pi/2)t} + 2 e^{i(2\pi/2)t} + (-4 + 2i) e^{i(3\pi/2)t}. \tag1
$$
On the next line it is claimed that
$$
x(t) \stackrel?=
 6 + (-4 - 2i) e^{i(\pi/2)t} + (-4 + 2i) e^{-i(\pi/2)t} + 2 e^{i\pi t}. \tag2
$$
Observing that the first, second, and third terms on the right side of Equation $(1)$ are equal to the first, second, and fourth terms on the right side of Equation $(2)$,
the claim in Equation $(2)$ comes down to a claim that
$$
(-4 + 2i) e^{i(3\pi/2)t} \stackrel?= (-4 + 2i) e^{-i(\pi/2)t}. \tag{*}
$$
Since $3\pi/2 = -\pi/2 + 2\pi,$ Equation $(\text{*})$ is true for every integer value of $t$, but [it is false for every other value of $t$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-4+%2B+2i%29+e%5E%28i%283%5Cpi%2F2%29t%29+-+%28-4+%2B+2i%29+e%5E%28-i%28%5Cpi%2F2%29t%29).

The next equation is a simple rearrangement of terms from Equation $(2)$:
$$
x(t) \stackrel?=
 6 - 4\left(e^{i(\pi/2)t} + e^{-i(\pi/2)t}\right)
 - 2i \left(e^{i(\pi/2)t} - e^{-i(\pi/2)t}\right) + 2 e^{i\pi t}. \tag3
$$

From this we are supposed to conclude that
$$
x(t) \stackrel?= 6 - 8 \cos((\pi/2)t) + 4 \sin((\pi/2)t) + 2\cos(\pi t). \tag4
$$
The first, second, and third terms of Equation $(4)$ are equal to the first three  terms of Equation $(3)$ by well-known trig identities.
In order to derive Equation $(4)$ from Equation $(3)$, then, we must believe that
$$
2 e^{i\pi t} \stackrel?= 2\cos(\pi t). \tag{**}
$$
Since $\cos(\theta) = \Re\left(e^{i\theta}\right),$
the real parts of both sides of Equation $(\text{**})$ match up all right,
but the imaginary parts do not.
Once again we have an equation that is true for every integer $t$ but
[false for every other value of $t$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+e%5E%28i%5Cpi+t%29+-+2%5Ccos%28%5Cpi+t%29).

If the final answer is correct it seems to me it could only be through previous lucky errors in the calculations before the final sequence of equations in the question.